# How can I enable or disable the home button on Android?

Tags: android

How can I enable or disable the home button on Android tablets?

Comment: You mean the home button?

Comment: fortunatelly home button cannot be disabled

Comment: Its like an `emergency` button for the user. Why would you want to take that away from them?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri for online transaction so only i want to disable that

Comment: when u want enable & when you want to disable it

Comment: @YogeshTatwal at the time of payment process initiated i want to disable and after complete process it will enable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15459920/1915697 please see this link

Comment: also see this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/9825766/1915697

Comment: There is no way to detect the HOME button pressed. One way you can handle it is that if your transaction is on UI thread, then you can check in `onPause()` method if the person is trying to pause the activity or sth. Other way which I can think of it to start a background process and do that transaction thing from there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079691/overriding-the-home-button-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-choice you can, but it's dangerous also, this question has been asked multiple times in the past

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183905/how-to-disable-home-button-in-android/17183967#17183967. you cannot disable home button. If you want to handle the HOME button, implement a home screen.

Comment: Thank you so much to all for sharing your ideas.